# How to forward engineer a manually inserted ER diagram to use it in SQL side?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I manually inserted my data into tables in ER Diagram side. Even though I forward engineer in different ways (checking different boxes) I keep getting error. If I don't check any boxes, I seem to have no errors but I have empty output when `select * from table_a in SQL`. Error I keep getting (I selected it as a default database):

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1046: No database selected

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema db
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `Genders`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Genders`
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch